# Why does LoginStatus control not redirect to login page on root of webserver?

Tags: asp.net

I am coding in asp.net 4.5 on IIS 8 and have a master page which has a LoginStatus control in the menus. This control is shown on every page.

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
CssClass="loginbutton" LoginText="Log In" Width="50" 
LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
```

If I browse to: `http://localhost/Default.aspx` page in the root of the site and click on Login, I am redirected to the Login page.

I have setup IIS to show Default.aspx as the default document. However, if I browse to: `http://localhost/` which shows the home page content correctly and click on the Login link, I am just redirected back to `http://localhost` and not the login page.

What do I need to do to make sure I can login from the homepage?

==================UPDATE==========================
I couldn't figure this out, so since the default document for the root of the site is 'default.aspx' (notice the lower case), I've put in the following code on Page_Load:

```
       if  (Request.Url.ToString().Contains("default.aspx"))
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

and I now if anyone goes to `http://localhost/` they are redirected to `http://localhost/Default.aspx` where the loginstatus control works fine. Still don't know the cause of the issue, but at least I have a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the login page in your `web.config`.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/folder/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: I have got this already in my Web.config (without the timeout). My problem is that this is not working on pages where the default document is presented, i.e. http://localhost.

Comment: Do you have routing or something else you can think that is conflicting with the redirect to the login page?

Comment: Try testing the method that the loginURL uses. For example create a button on your default page and onClick redirect using the method `FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a solution. I believe i have the exact same issue. The button appears to not post back unless the url has the aspx file in it. e.g. www.mydomain.com/ does not work but www.mydomain.com/index.aspx does.
I have have hacked a solution together using url mappings.

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
            <add url="~/" mappedUrl="~/index.aspx" />
    </urlMappings>
```

This does work but not exactly elegant. 
This occurred when i upgraded to a new server with iis 8.
I would love to know if you did find a better solution.
Thank you